# Unable to connect to running rabbitmq services route on openshift

Tags: rabbitmq, openshift, spring-cloud-stream

my company have i runing microservice project deployed with openshift.

and existing services success to connect to rabbitmq service with this properties on it's code ,

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbitmq.host: rabbitmq
spring.cloud.stream.rabbitmq.port: 5672
```

now i'm developing new service, with my laptop, not deployed to openshift yet, and now i'm trying to connect to the same broker as the others, so i created new route for rabbitmq service with 5672 as it's port

this is my route YAML :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-amqp
  namespace: message-broker
  selfLink: /oapi/v1/namespaces/message-broker/routes/rabbitmq-amqp
  uid: 5af3e903-a8ad-11e7-8370-005056aca8b0
  resourceVersion: '21744899'
  creationTimestamp: '2017-10-04T02:40:16Z'
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
  annotations:
    openshift.io/host.generated: 'true'
spec:
  host: rabbitmq-amqp-message-broker.apps.fifgroup.co.id
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: rabbitmq
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 5672-tcp
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  wildcardPolicy: None
status:
  ingress:
    - host: rabbitmq-amqp-message-broker.apps.fifgroup.co.id
      routerName: router
      conditions:
        - type: Admitted
          status: 'True'
          lastTransitionTime: '2017-10-04T02:40:16Z'
      wildcardPolicy: None
```

when i;m trying to connect my new service with this properties :

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbitmq.host: rabbitmq-amqp-message-broker.apps.fifgroup.co.id
spring.cloud.stream.rabbitmq.port: 80
```

and my service failed to set the connection.

how to solve this problem?
where should i fix it? my service routes or my service properties..?

Thank for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passthrough secure connection to expose a non HTTP server outside of the cluster, your service must terminate a TLS connection and your client must also support SNI over TLS. Do you have both of those? Right now it seems you are trying to connect on port 80 anyway, which means it must be HTTP. Isn't RabbitMQ non HTTP? If you are only trying to connect to it from a front end app in the same OpenShift cluster, you don't need a Route on rabbitmq, use 'rabbitmq' as host name and use port 5672.

Comment: thank for your respon, but correct me if i'mm wrong, because i;m new with openshift.
i want to connect  it outside from openshift cluster because i on development phase and it require me to do a lot of debbuging. 
i used port 80 because port cannot be null, and it's default value it 5672, and i;m using port 80 because 80 is default port for route.
so is it possible to create amqp route ( not http ) for my rabbitmyq service?

Comment: or maybe, is it possible to call my service by it's IP outside of openshift cluster? my laptop is still inside the same network as my company openshift dedicated server.

Comment: If it is a temporary connection that you require during development or debugging, so you can connect to it from an application running on your local machine, you can use port forwarding. See the port forwarding tutorial at https://learn.openshift.com Whether you can expose it externally over a permanent port assigned to the service yourself, will depend on the confguration of the OpenShift cluster. Something more permanent may require administrator access. If temporary, better to use port forwarding.